# Compute with a recursive function defined by well-defined induction

Tags: coq

When I use `Function` to define a non-structurally recursive function in Coq, the resulting object behaves strangely when a specific computation is asked. Indeed, instead of giving directly the result, the `Eval compute in ...` directive return a rather long (typically 170 000 lines) expression. It seems that Coq cannot evaluate everything, and therefore returns a simplified (but long) expression instead of just a value.

The problem seems to come from the way I prove the obligations generated by `Function`. First, I thought the problem came from the opaque terms I used, and I converted all the lemmas to transparent constants. By the way, is there a way to list the opaque terms appearing in a term ? Or any other way to turn opaque lemmas into transparent ones ?

I then remarked that the problem came more precisely from the proof that the order used is well-founded. But I got strange results.

For example, I define `log2` on the natural numbers by repeatedly applying `div2`. Here is the definition:

```
Function log2 n {wf lt n} :=
  match n with
  | 0 => 0
  | 1 => 0
  | n => S (log2 (Nat.div2 n))
  end.
```

I get two proof obligations. The first one checks that `n` respects the relation `lt` in the recursive calls and can be proved easily.

```
forall n n0 n1 : nat, n0 = S n1 -> n = S (S n1) -> Nat.div2 (S (S n1)) < S (S n1)

intros. apply Nat.lt_div2. apply le_n_S. apply le_0_n.
```

The second one checks that `lt` is a well-founded order. This is already proved in the standard library. The corresponding lemma is `Coq.Arith.Wf_nat.lt_wf`.

If I use this proof, the resulting function behaves normally. `Eval compute in log24 10.` returns `3`.

But if I want to do the proof myself, I do not always get this behaviour. First, if I end the proof with `Qed` instead of `Defined`, the result of the computation (even on small numbers) is a complex expression and not a single number. So I use `Defined` and try to use only transparent lemmas.

```
Lemma lt_wf2 : well_founded lt.
Proof.
  unfold well_founded. intros n.
  apply (lemma1 n). clear n.
  intros. constructor. apply H.
Defined.
```

Here, lemma1 is a proof of the well-founded induction on the natural numbers. Here again, I can use already existing lemmas, such as `lt_wf_ind`, `lt_wf_rec`, `lt_wf_rec1` located in `Coq.Arith.Wf_nat`, or even `well_founded_ind lt_wf`. The first one does not work, it seems this is because it is opaque. The three others work.

I tried to prove it directly using the standard induction on the natural numbers, `nat_ind`. This gives:

```
Lemma lemma1 : forall n (P:nat -> Prop),
  (forall n, (forall p, p < n -> P p) -> P n) -> P n.
Proof.
  intros n P H. pose proof (nat_ind (fun n => forall p, p < n -> P p)).
  simpl in H0. apply H0 with (n:=S n).
  - intros. inversion H1.
  - intros. inversion H2.
    + apply H. exact H1.
    + apply H1. assumption.
  - apply le_n.
Defined.
```

With this proof (and some variants of it), `log2` has the same strange behaviour. And this proof seems to use only transparent objects, so maybe the problem is not there.

How can I define a `Function` that returns understandable results on specific values ?

Comment: `Print Opaque Dependencies log2` can be used to list the opaque terms used in `log2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to pin-point the place that causes troubles: it's `inversion H2.` in `lemma1`. It turns out we don't need that case-analysis and `intuition` can finish the proof (it doesn't pattern-match on `H2`):

```
Lemma lemma1 : forall n (P:nat -> Prop),
  (forall n, (forall p, p < n -> P p) -> P n) -> P n.
Proof.
  intros n P H. pose proof (nat_ind (fun n => forall p, p < n -> P p)).
  simpl in H0. apply H0 with (n:=S n).
  - intros. inversion H1.
  - intros. intuition.
  - apply le_n.
Defined.
```

If we use `lemma1` with this proof, the computation of `log2 10` results in `3`.

By the way, here is my version of `lt_wf2` (it lets us compute as well):

```
Lemma lt_wf2 : well_founded lt.
Proof.
  unfold well_founded; intros n.
  induction n; constructor; intros k Hk.
  - inversion Hk.
  - constructor; intros m Hm.
    apply IHn; omega.
 (* OR: apply IHn, Nat.lt_le_trans with (m := k); auto with arith. *)
Defined.
```

I believe the
[Using Coq's evaluation mechanisms in anger](http://gallium.inria.fr/blog/coq-eval/) blog post by Xavier Leroy explains this kind of behavior.

> it eliminates the proof of equality between the heads before recursing over the tails and finally deciding whether to produce a left or a right. This makes the left/right data part of the final result dependent on a proof term, which in general does not reduce!

In our case we eliminate the proof of inequality (`inversion H2.`) in the proof of `lemma1` and the `Function` mechanism makes our computations depend on a proof term. Hence, the evaluator can't proceed when n > 1.

And the reason `inversion H1.` in the body of the lemma doesn't influence computations is that for `n = 0` and `n = 1`, `log2 n` is defined within the `match` expression as base cases.

To illustrate this point, let me show an example when we can prevent evaluation of `log2 n` on any values `n` and `n + 1` of our choice, where `n > 1` and *nowhere else*!

```
Lemma lt_wf2' : well_founded lt.
Proof.
  unfold well_founded; intros n.
  induction n; constructor; intros k Hk.
  - inversion Hk.          (* n = 0 *)
  - destruct n. intuition. (* n = 1 *)
    destruct n. intuition. (* n = 2 *)
    destruct n. intuition. (* n = 3 *)
    destruct n. inversion Hk; intuition. (* n = 4 and n = 5 - won't evaluate *)
    (* n > 5 *)
    constructor; intros m Hm; apply IHn; omega.
Defined.
```

If you use this modified lemma in the definition of `log2` you'll see that it computes everywhere except `n = 4` and `n = 5`. Well, almost everywhere -- computations with large `nat`s can result in *stack overflow* or segmentation fault, as Coq warns us:

> Warning: Stack overflow or segmentation fault happens when working with
>    large numbers in nat (observed threshold may vary from 5000 to 70000
>    depending on your system limits and on the command executed).

And to make `log2` work for `n = 4` and `n = 5` even for the above "flawed" proof, we could amend `log2` like this

```
Function log2 n {wf lt n} :=
  match n with
  | 0 => 0
  | 1 => 0
  | 4 => 2
  | 5 => 2
  | n => S (log2 (Nat.div2 n))
  end.
```

adding the necessary proofs at the end.

---

The "well-founded" proof must be transparent and can't rely on pattern-matching on proof objects because the `Function` mechanism actually uses the `lt_wf` lemma to compute the decreasing termination guard. If we look at the term produced by `Eval` (in a case where evaluation fails to produce a `nat`), we'll see something along these lines:

```
fix Ffix (x : nat) (x0 : Acc (fun x0 x1 : nat => S x0 <= x1) x) {struct x0}
```

It's easy to see that `x0 : Prop`, so it gets erased when extracting the functional program `log2` into, say OCaml, but Coq's internal evaluation mechanism have to use it to ensure termination.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to Xavier Leroy's post. Very clear and informative.

Comment: Your `lt_wf2'` is very convincing. What remains unclear to me is why the well-founded proof must be transparent and if it could be avoided.

Comment: Thanks. That is more or less what I expected. The remaining question is: is this behaviour due to the way `Function` is implemented or will it be present in every implementation ?

Comment: I think it's a major design decision for `Function` to make extraction eligible. Basically, `Function` adds one dummy argument and turns (under the hood) your unary function into a binary one. But this dummy argument doesn't necessarily have to live in `Prop`. [Here](https://gist.github.com/anton-trunov/c3144d1a6e11ac023b65be6d36bf3253) is an example how we could've achieved almost the same thing with `Fixpoint`, except for the fact that the extracted function does some excessive amount of work. Sorry, if I headed the wrong way -- it's a bit unclear to me what you meant.

Comment: I was talking about the fact that opaque terms used in the decreasing argument prevent evaluation inside Coq. Is it due to an implementation choice of `Function` or cannot it be really avoided?

Comment: Notice that not all opaque terms prevent evaluation. I've made an [explicit version](https://gist.github.com/anton-trunov/c9e6bd31d26b24e63349a9e217a1f9f4) of what `Function` does (I've tried to preserve the spirit, not to provide the real implementation). The opaque terms created with `Nat.lt_div2` and `Nat.lt_0_succ` do not prevent evaluation. If our usage of opaque terms prevents evaluation to the weak head normal form for the termination guard, then we'll get stuck. And that would happen if we destructed some proof term like `(y < n)`.

Answer (score 2):

The reduction behavior of functions defined by well-founded recursion in Coq is generally not very good, even when you declare your proofs to be transparent. The reason for this is that arguments of well-foundedness usually need to be done with complicated proof terms. Since these proofs terms end up appearing in well-founded recursive definitions, "simplifying" your function will make all of those proof terms appear, as you noticed.

It is easier to rely on custom tactics and lemmas to reduce functions defined this way. First, I would recommend favoring `Program Fixpoint` over `Function`, because the latter is much older and (I think) less well maintained. Thus, you would end up with a definition like this:

```
Require Import Coq.Numbers.Natural.Peano.NPeano.
Require Import Coq.Program.Wf.
Require Import Coq.Program.Tactics.

Program Fixpoint log2 n {wf lt n} :=
  match n with
  | 0 => 0
  | 1 => 0
  | n => S (log2 (Nat.div2 n))
  end.

Next Obligation.
admit.
Qed.
```

Now, you just need to use the `program_simpl` tactic to simplify calls to `log2`. Here's an example:

```
Lemma foo : log2 4 = 2.
Proof.
  program_simpl.
Qed.
```

Comment: Ok, this is an alternative. But I would have liked to understand what is going on with this `Function` stuff. Moreover, I do not know how to reason with `Program Fixpoint`. How can I get the functional recursion and equation lemmas that I can get with `Function` using `Functional Scheme` ?

Comment: @eponier I think it should be possible to prove them directly using well-founded induction and the `program_simpl` tactic.

Comment: I managed to prove both `log25_equation` and `log25_ind` using `fix_sub_eq` and `Fix_sub_rect` respectively (in `Coq.Program.Wf`). I do not know if it is the best solution. And one error in my previous comment: `Function` automatically generates the equation and functional induction lemmas. `Functional Scheme` is useful for classic `Fixpoint`.